# Getting the most recent of a group of repeated rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table 'UserLibrary'

```
   Name  Library    AccessedTime

    A      ABC       2:00 am
    B      XYZ       4:00 am
    C      PQR       5:00 am 
    C      PQR       12:00 pm 
    C      PQR       2:00 pm
    D      LIT       4:00 pm
```

I want a list of distinct users, Library and their last accessed time.

Select * from UserLibrary, will give me repeated rows for user 'C' and Library 'PQR' , but i want the last accessed time only for user C.

so basically i Want,

```
   Name  Library    AccessedTime

    A      ABC       2:00 am
    B      XYZ       4:00 am 
    C      PQR       2:00 pm
    D      LIT       4:00 pm
```

How can i do this in Sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Name, Library, max(AccessedTime) as 'AccessedTime'
from UserLibrary
group by Name, Library
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which generates sequential number which you can filtered with. In this case, the sequential number is generated for every `name` and `library` and sorted on the latest `AccessedTime`. The latest records will have a value of `1` on `rn`.

```
SELECT Name, Library, AccessedTime
FROM
(
    SELECT  Name, Library, AccessedTime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name, Library
                                ORDER BY AccessedTime DESC) rn
    FROM    UserLibrary
) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: THanks, Man... Thats the quickest answer I have ever got :-)

Comment: this can help if you have more other columns having different values on it.